# Can't map a network drive through VPN (it works over the regular network)

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, vpn, network-shares, windows-firewall

I need to map a network drive over VPN. The server is running Windows Vista Business 64-bit and the client runs Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.

The computers are on two different networks. Windows firewall is enabled with the relevant rules to allow File and Printer sharing. **Everything works fine over the regular network** but fails when trying to go through VPN. I know the VPN works because I can ping the server using the VPN assigned ip address and I remote desktop through it as well.

I've tried mapping the drive both through Explorer and the `net use` command.

```
net use \\172.16.1.1\C /user:name@domain
net use \\172.16.1.1\C /user:name@IP_ADDRESS
net use \\172.16.1.1\C /user:domain/name
```

I either get the error saying `The network path was not found` or `There are no logon servers available to service the logon request.`

The event log on the server shows that `A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.` but from the regular network ip address as opposed to the VPN address.

EDIT:
Neither computer is a member of a domain and both are in the same default work group (WORKGROUP).

Comment: Part of an AD domain? It could be that you are unable to reach the KDC over the VPN, and Windows is attempting NTLM instead ("explicit credentials"). Also, it might help to check using Wireshark what exactly goes over the network.

Comment: @grawity Hi, neither computers are part of a domain and they are in the same default workgroup (i.e. 'WORKGROUP'). Downloading Wireshark now...